# Killing all python interpreters but the one which launches kill command

Tags: python, linux, scripting, kill

Any idea on how to kill every python interpreter running on a GNU/Linux machine but the one which's launching the kill command (which is a python script itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is find your current PID (Process ID):

```
import os
mypid = os.getpid()
```

Now using psutil, find every process running a python interpreter

```
import psutil
for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.name == 'python.exe' and process.pid != mypid:
        process.kill() # or send_signal(signal)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the killer script use `os.getpid()` to find the current pid

Then filter this out of the list of pids to be destroyed